# What things to consider for home gardening in West facing balcony?

Tags: houseplants, sunlight

I've moved to a home where the balcony is West facing, which means direct sunlight comes only in the second half of the day (after ~01:00 PM depending on the season, tropical India is the climate).

What all things should I consider to grow herbs from seeds in small pots? I intend to grow standard herbs and flowers like salvia, marigold, gomphrena, etc.

Comment: I think that the herbs will be fine.  I wouldnt try larger plants.

Comment: If it's the only garden space you have available, simply try growing the things you would like to grow there.

Comment: Use something in the pots that holds water, like coco peat. And try to shade the actual pot so it doesn’t cook. I have a similar balcony

Answer (score 1):

**This does not answer the question as it violates the "in small pots" requirement. It is being posted as hopefully useful but too long for a comment**

The herb idea is great. You can also try tomatoes as they - being a rapidly growing vine - are easy to shape into anything that absorbs the sunlight. Just be sure to have enough nitrogen in the soil.

It's all about *where* is sun being shined. <outside the equator and polar regions> in summer it's almost vertical, in winter it's almost horizontal.

As a sidenote, here's a quote from a local gardening newspaper**:

> Tomatoes and cucumbers have the ability to produce additional roots. So if observing [stunted growth*] additional soil can be deposited onto the bottom of the stem to provoke that.

> I consider to grow herbs from seeds in small pots

Germination is unaffected but stunted growth is possible if not careful. [And dangerous.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63907/tomato-seedling-care/63943#comment84439_63943)

<sub>* - the text names a non-fatal illness but I am not aquainted with it and fail to even translate the name to English</sub>
<sub>** - I do not endorse it as I've never observed the process to completion. However a gardening newspaper sounds credible</sub>